# Como inserir um texto num p:editor?

Tags: primefaces

Tenho um `<p:editor />` e preciso inserir textos predefinidos na posição atual do cursor.

Já andei procurando na documentação do Primefaces e não achei nada parecido (consigo limpar usando `PF('editor').clear()` mas não achei nada para inserir texto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a resposta no fórum do Primefaces [post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44127&p=137943#p137943)

```
PF('edt').editor.execCommand('inserthtml','texto inserido');
```